# Hidden column header getting displayed when rendered in Quarto Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, quarto, gt

I have a simple quarto markdown which generates table using `gt` package from a data frame.

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---
```
```{r,include = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r, include = FALSE}
intro <- data.frame("Name" = "Python",
                    "Age" = "33",
                    "Height" = "14")
```
````

When I use the `pivot_longer()`, `name` and `value` column header gets generated. So to remove that I have used `column_labels.hidden = TRUE`.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
intro %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_column_labels(columns = 1)
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(columns = 1)
  ) 
```
````

When I run this in the code chunk it works as expected showing without the column header and  the desired cell text is in bold.

**Problem**:
When I render this, all the format gets lost. Even the `name` and `value` shows up in the final table.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way using `flextable` package.

```
std_border = fp_border(color="black")
ft <- intro %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  flextable()


ft <- ft |> 
  delete_part( part = "header") |> 
  border_remove() |> 
  hline( part="all", border = std_border ) |> 
  vline( border = std_border ) |> 
  vline_left(border = std_border ) |> 
  hline_top(part="all", border = std_border)|> 
  autofit()
ft
```